# Find (replace) the last space in any HTML headings within block of HTML

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to come up with some regex which I can use to replace the last space character with a non-breaking space (control widows) within headings only inside a block of HTML.

So far I have this:

```
const regex = /(<h.>.+?)\s+((\S|<[^>]+>)*)\n|$/gi
const replaced = text.replace(regex, '$1&nbsp;$2')
```

In regex101 it looks like it works correctly but when running in JavaScript it adds an extra `&nbsp` to the end of the string.

A sample block of HTML might look like this:

```html
<h2>This is a test heading</h2>
<p>Here is some text</p>
<div>
  <h3>Here is a another heading</h3>
  <p>Some more paragraph text which shouldn't match</p>
</div>
```

Which should be replaced with:

```html
<h2>This is a test&nbsp;heading</h2>
<p>Here is some text</p>
<div>
  <h3>Here is a another&nbsp;heading</h3>
  <p>Some more paragraph text which shouldn't match</p>
</div>
```

A [link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8xfVOj/1) showing the working pattern.

Below is a snippet showing the non-working behaviour in JavaScript:

```js
let text = "<h2>This is a test heading</h2>"
const regex = /(<h.>.+?)\s+((\S|<h.>)*)\n|$/gi
let replaced = text.replace(regex, '$1&nbsp;$2')
console.log(replaced);

text = `<h2>This is a test heading</h2>
<p>Here is some text</p>
<div>
  <h3>Here is a another heading</h3>
  <p>Some more paragraph text which shouldn't match</p>
  <p>Why is there a non breaking space at the very end?</p>
</div>`
replaced = text.replace(regex, '$1&nbsp;$2')
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: Change the regex to `const regex = /(<h\d+>[^<]*?)\s+((<[^>]+>|\S)*)$/gim`. Probably `\S` should be replaced with `[^\s<>]`. However, it would be easier if you parse HTML with a DOM parser and just work on the plain text with regex or even without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we would be starting with a simple expression to capture the undesired space as well as other possible spaces that might come right before the last word using this capturing group `(\s+)`:

```
<(h[1-6])>(.+)(\s+)([^\s]+)<\/\1>
```

If we wish to add more constraints to our expression, we can certainly do so.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RHqxhL/1)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /<(h[1-6])>(.+)(\s+)([^\s]+)<\/\1>/gim;
const str = `<h2>This is a test heading</h2>
<p>Here is some text</p>
<div>
  <h3>Here is a another heading</h3>
  <p>Some more paragraph text which shouldn't match</p>
</div>
<h2>This is a test   heading</h2>
<p>Here is some text</p>
<div>
  <h3>Here is a another    heading</h3>
  <p>Some more paragraph text which shouldn't match</p>
</div>`;
const subst = `<$1>$2&nbsp;$4<\/$1>`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RHqxhL/1).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution. I made a slight change to accommodate tags with attributes, classes etc:
`const regex = /<(h[1-6])(.*?)>(.+)(\s+)([^\s]+)<\/\1>/gim;
const subst = `<$1$2>$3&nbsp;$5<\/$1>`
`
This copes with headings that have a class as well as ones that don't.

Comment: As code blocks don't work in comments I added an additional answer to clarify in case others find it useful. Have accepted yours as a working solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
var regex = /(<(h\d+)>[^<]*?)\s+([^\s<]*?<\/\2>)/gi;
```

Replace with `'$1&nbsp;$3'`.

**Details**

- `(<(h\d+)>[^<]*?)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `<`, then `(h\d+)` captures into Group 2 a `h` and 1+ digits, then `>` is matched and then any 0 or more chars other than `<`, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([^\s<]*?<\/\2>)` - Group 3 (`$3`): any chars other than whitespace and `<` as possible, and then a correspomding close tag: `</`, same value as in Group 2 (`\2` is an in-pattern backreference) and then a `>`.

JS demo:

```js
var text = "<h2>This is a test heading</h2>\n<p>Here is some text</p>\n<div>\n  <h3>Here is a another heading</h3>\n  <p>Some more paragraph text which shouldn't match</p>\n</div>";
var regex = /(<(h\d+)>[^<]*?)\s+([^\s<]*?<\/\2>)/gi;
var replaced = text.replace(regex, '$1&nbsp;$3');
console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the accepted answer to cope with attributes on the tag:

```
const regex = /<(h[1-6])(.*?)>(.+)(\s+)([^\s]+)<\/\1>/gim;
const subst = `<$1$2>$3&nbsp;$5<\/$1>`
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
```

This allows for more flexibility on the opening tag.